# Keycloak spring boot: tengo error al intrentar autorizar los recursos con un access token

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, keycloak

---

**Título:** Error al consumir servicio autenticado: `java.lang.RuntimeException: Must set 'realm' in config`

Estoy obteniendo un error al intentar consumir un servicio autenticado. Aquí está el error completo:

```java
java.lang.RuntimeException: Must set 'realm' in config
    at org.keycloak.adapters.KeycloakDeploymentBuilder.internalBuild(KeycloakDeploymentBuilder.java:57) ~[keycloak-adapter-core-12.0.1.jar:12.0.1]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.KeycloakDeploymentBuilder.build(KeycloakDeploymentBuilder.java:202) ~[keycloak-adapter-core-12.0.1.jar:12.0.1]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.springboot.KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver.resolve(KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver.java:41) ~[keycloak-spring-boot-adapter-core-12.0.1.jar:12.0.1]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.config.KeycloakSpringConfigResolverWrapper.resolve(KeycloakSpringConfigResolverWrapper.java:40) ~[keycloak-spring-security-adapter-12.0.1.jar:12.0.1]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.AdapterDeploymentContext.resolveDeployment(AdapterDeploymentContext.java:89) ~[keycloak-adapter-core-12.0.1.jar:12.0.1]
```

Genero el access token y luego intento consumir el servicio con el token, pero Spring genera un error que indica que debo establecer la propiedad del 'realm'. Aquí están mis propiedades y parte del código:

**Propiedades**

```
server.port=8081

spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.client.client-id=client
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.client.authorization-grant-type=authorization_code
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.client.scope=openid,email,profile,roles
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.client.provider=keycloak

spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.keycloak.authorization-uri=http://localhost:8085/realms/user/protocol/openid-connect/auth
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.keycloak.token-uri=http://localhost:8085/realms/user/protocol/openid-connect/token
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.keycloak.user-info-uri=http://localhost:8085/realms/user/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.keycloak.jwk-set-uri=http://localhost:8085/realms/user/protocol/openid-connect/certs
```

**Código de configuración de seguridad:**

```java
package com.djamware.oauthresource.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors()
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/board")
            .hasAuthority("user")
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .and()
            .oauth2ResourceServer()
            .jwt();
    }
}
```

Agradecería cualquier ayuda para resolver este problema. Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

acabo de tener el mismo problema y lo solucione agregando las configuraciones del keycloak en el properties, prueba a ver si también te sirve.

Configuraciones del keycloak:

```
#==============================[KEYCLOAK CONFIG]==============================

keycloak.realm= demo
keycloak.auth-server-url= http://localhost:8080
keycloak.ssl-required= external
keycloak.resource= {CLIENTE}
keycloak.credentials.secret= {CREDENTIAL}
keycloak.use-resource-role-mappings = true
keycloak.allow-any-hostname = true
keycloak.enable-basic-auth = false
keycloak.disable-trust-manager = true
keycloak.bearer-only = true
keycloak.cors = true
```

Answer (score 0):

Te cuento ttu SecurityConfig esta decprecado te enseño como se hace actualmente

```
@Configuration
@OpenAPIDefinition(security = @SecurityRequirement(name = "bearerAuth"))
@SecurityScheme(name = "bearerAuth", type = SecuritySchemeType.HTTP, scheme = "bearer", bearerFormat = "JWT")
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, prePostEnabled = true)
@AllArgsConstructor
class WebSecurityConfig {

    private final JwtPuntoDAutentificacion jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint;

    private final JwtRequestFilter jwtRequestFilter;

    @Bean
    BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration)
            throws Exception {
        return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        return httpSecurity.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable).authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                .requestMatchers(PathRequest.toStaticResources().atCommonLocations()).permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/autenticacion/login").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/v3/api-docs/**"),
                        new AntPathRequestMatcher("/h2-console/**"), new AntPathRequestMatcher("/swagger-ui/**"),
                        new AntPathRequestMatcher("/swagger-ui.html"), new AntPathRequestMatcher("/w2m.html"))
                .permitAll().requestMatchers(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/SuperHeroe/**")).authenticated().anyRequest()
                .authenticated())
                .exceptionHandling(
                        exceptionHandling -> exceptionHandling.authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint))
                .sessionManagement(
                        sessionManagement -> sessionManagement.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class).build();
    }

    @Bean
    WebSecurityCustomizer webSecurityCustomizer() {
        return web -> web.ignoring().requestMatchers(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/h2-console/**"));
    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        final CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(List.of("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(List.of("HEAD", "GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "PATCH", "OPTIONS"));
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(List.of("*"));
        configuration.setExposedHeaders(List.of("X-Auth-Token", "Authorization", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials"));

        final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
}
```

el allarge es de lombok no seria necesario solo sustityuye al constructor
@OpenAPIDefinition(security = @SecurityRequirement(name = "bearerAuth"))
@SecurityScheme(name = "bearerAuth", type = SecuritySchemeType.HTTP, scheme = "bearer", bearerFormat = "JWT") esas son de swager para la securizacion